# Can't reset Arduino Pro Micro

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-micro, atmega32u4, genuino

I'm trying to reset an [Arduino Pro Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro) with a new code and it is not allowing me to. I'm using an empty sketch to upload to the pro micro but I get different error messages every time. I think the reason why it doesn't allow me to upload code is because it is programmed to start on boot. As soon as it's plugged in to a USB port the code runs, and causes this issue.

Some of the errors I get is

```
Arduino: 1.8.2 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Micro"

Sketch uses 3602 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 147 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2413 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Device or resource busy
Problem uploading to board.`
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try pressing the reset button twice?

Comment: Sounds like ModemManager is locking the port.

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah I have tried pressing the reset button twice and then uploading the empty code quickly as soon as the port is identified but no luck

Comment: @Majenko That blog post seems like it's about accessing ports, I have access to my COMPORT and I can get my board info from the ide, so the ports aren't the issue.

Comment: Trust me. Look at the modem manager part.

Comment: You plug the board in (or it is reset to enter the bootloader). Immediately modem manager opens the port and tries to configure it, which means you can't since it's busy. It fails, since it isn't a modem, and releases the port. From that point you can access it, but it's too late for programming by then.

Comment: @Majenko I plug the board in and within 500 miliseconds it starts typing several strings onto the computer which is I programmed it to be. Now from my understanding to completely reset the board I need to have an empty sketch on the ide, press the reset button on the board and click on upload on the ide but by the time It resets and connects to a port it's already typing things onto the computer so it's almost impossible to click reset before 500 miliseconds.

Comment: It typing things won't make the port be busy. Only software running in Linux can do that, and the only software that is normally doing that is ModemManager.

Comment: @Majenko I will try to reset it on MacOsx see if I get the same error.

Comment: managed to fix it @Majenko using the Mac OSX Arduino IDE even after my code executed it seems it is modernmanager on Linux, every time I would hit upload on Linux it would rerun my code on the board almost as if it it was hitting the reset button. But on mac all I did was wait until the code finished running, and then I hit upload and it worked!

Comment: @Majenko: you should have mentioned modemmanager, save the poor guy some time...

Comment: @dandavis You think? ;) Maybe I should have mentioned modemmanager instead.

Comment: haha post an answer I will accept it